# Angular 4 API infinite call once API service is disconnected

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I was working on Angular 4 application using c# web api as service, got in to an issue like after login and having multiple API calls, if API application is stopped and then doing a API call using a button click from Angular UI is causing infinite API calls like the same API calls are iterating again and again.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, something may be wrong with how you subscribe. Unless you have a retry.

Comment: export declare function catchError<T, R>(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T | R>;

Comment: while some error happens in http service this function is being invoke, can anyone help me understand this

Comment: what is the catch error outputting? That should be your answer

Comment: Hi @TaranjitKang thanks for the time, still the issue persists , even login button without running API backgroud is causing the issue

Comment: get<TResponse>(path: string): Observable<TResponse> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //this.appendAuthHeader(headers);
    return this.http.get<TResponse>(path, { headers: headers }).pipe(
      tap(resp => this.log(resp)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

Comment: this is how i am calling a service.

Comment: catch box is the internal rxjs catch block

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue, for router reload we have given a code inside constructor :

```
this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
  // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-initalise the component
  if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.ngOnInit();
  }
});
```

this was causing a loop ...